# Heroku pg:pull pg_dump extension/library version mismatch

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, pg-dump

I've just upgraded my Heroku app's PostgreSQL to version 12.

I'm currently having an issue with Heroku's pg:pull, where the extension/library from the server's `pg_dump` is apparently an older version:

```
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  incompatible library "/usr/local/lib/postgresql/btree_gin.so": version mismatch
DETAIL:  Server is version 10, library is version 12.
Command was: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gin WITH SCHEMA public;
```

The command I run is: `heroku pg:pull ${SERVER_DB} ${DEV_DB} -a ${APP}`

I have attempted `ALTER EXTENSION btree_gin UPDATE;` but it wasn't any help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that this error was concerning my local machine's PostgreSQL server version—not the server on Heroku.

Doing `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` would resolve this by upgrading the server version.

I ended up just deleting my existing local database and reinstalling PostgreSQL instead because running `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` involves copying entire tables; I didn't have enough space in local storage.